# BKMR probit and thinning

Tags: bayesian

is there a way to thin the BKMR models in the kmbayes function with the probit option (for dichotomous outcome) or suggestions to improve the traceplot convergence? I'm using the BKMRhat and BKMR package.

So far, I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.